# Action Sheet Dialog actions color

Tags: dialog, nativescript, nativescript-angular

How to change action dialog actions button to red/destructive color in iOS and Android as well?
Is it supported with the current implementation of Nativescript?

I read that iOS supports destructive buttons color in the action sheet but I can't seem to find anything about its implementation on nativescript.

Comment: Destructive style is not supported in NativeScript implemention, you may have to access the native APIs directly to build your own action sheet with destructive buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Use [nativescript-fancyalert](https://www.nsplugins.com/plugin/nativescript-fancyalert) plugin for change action dialog action button color.